# Нужны ли кавычки после "как бы"?

Tags: кавычки

Пророк воплощает в жизни все то, что завещано Кораном, то есть он является как бы "живым Кораном".
Нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да пусть стоят - есть же не просят.

Автор всегда имеет право на кавычки, под которыми (внутри которых) может таиться любой оттенок авторского отношения к слову/явлению, а читатель *волнительно* становится соавтором...

Ну ты подумай: что за *живой Коран* без кавычек. И "как бы" им не подмога.

Comment: Я как раз думал, что  "как бы" могут заменять кавычки, поэтому и был вопрос.

Comment: Можно и по-другому. *Пророк **претворяет** в жизни всё то, что завещано Кораном, то есть он является как бы **воплощением Корана**.*

Comment: Нет, с кав. правильно. Ведь смысл немного разный: Пророк - воплощение и Пророк - Коран.